# Пчему ошибка только в IE<=9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, строки

Например, есть массив `fs=['AabB','AAbB'];` и код:

```
var reg = /([a-z]|[A-Z])\1/gi;
for (var i in fs) {
    var fsb = fs[i].match(reg);
    for (var u in fsb) {
        console.log(typeof (fsb[u]));
        if (fsb[u].charAt(1) == fsb[u].charAt(1).toUpperCase()) {
            fsb[u] = fsb[u].charAt(1) + fsb[u].charAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

После выполнения кода  в Opera Safari Chromium FireFox `fs=['AaBb','AABb'];`
Но в IE<=9 ошибка, Строка: 5.

> Ошибка: Объект не поддерживает свойство или метод "charAt"

Почему так, не могу понять, ведь в консоли написано `string string string string ...`
***UPD*** заменил все for... in и ошибка исчезла:

```
for (var i = 0; i < fs.length; i++) {
    var fsb = fs[i].match(reg);
    for (var u = 0; u < fsb.length; u++) {
        if (fsb[u].charAt(1) == fsb[u].charAt(1).toUpperCase()) {
            fsb[u] = fsb[u].charAt(1) + fsb[u].charAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Элементы массивов нельзя проходить с помощью `for (key in arr)`

ТОЛЬКО: `for(i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++)`

Comment: заменил for (var i in fs) на for(i = 0, l = fs.length; i < l; i++)  ошибка та же!

Comment: а второй цикл?
а проверка на null?

Comment: Да заменил оба, сработало, спасибо, это баг IE? XD

Comment: @Rules, вам уже говорили про for..in раз пять, а вы всё равно на грабли наступаете.

Comment: Sorry так привык к for (key in arr) не могу отвыкнуть :)

Comment: Кстати, везде кроме данного кода, for in нигде не вызывал ошибок и вообще я же не знал, что ошибка в нём, да она к тому же потому что массив с нечисловыми индексами, а 'ассоциативный' и не минусуйте, пожалуйста :)

Comment: > for in нишде не вызывал ошибок

А большинство ошибок в ДНК никак не проявляются до тридцатипятилетнего возраста. Загуглите, на эту тему тонны (буквально!) текстов написаны. Или, на худой конец, задайте прямой вопрос, и вам накидают ссылок. Неужели не интересно научиться?

Comment: при for...in обходятся все свойства, и есть у массива такое свойство как length... в нормальных браузерах у него флаг не итерируемости.

Comment: [] проходим for(;;), {} проходим for(in). только так.